# Update mysql on wordpress not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create a plugin that can update data on mysql on my installed Wordpress but I see is not working the update, I can see the form on my admin link, and also I can access to the form, but when I full up the forms and hit Enregistrer nothing change on my table, I did try a lot of solutions found on internet but it's not working.

```html
function test_defaultval() {
 echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '"
method="post">';
 echo '<p>';
 echo 'perdiodecite (requis) <br />';
 echo '<input type="text" name="cf-period" required pattern="[0-1]+"
size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';
 echo '<p>';
 echo 'ville (requis) <br />';
 echo '<input type="text" name="cf-ville" required size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';
 echo '<p>';
 echo 'author (requis) <br />';
 echo '<input type="text" name="cf-author" required pattern="[0-1]+"
size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';
 echo 'editor (requis) <br />';
 echo '<input type="text" name="cf-editor" required pattern="[0-1]+"
size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';
 echo 'contrubutor (requis) <br />';
 echo '<input type="text" name="cf-contrub" required pattern="[0-1]+"
size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';
 echo 'abonne (requis) <br />';
 echo '<input type="text" name="cf-abonne" required pattern="[0-1]+"
size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';

 echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted"
value="Enregistrer"/></p>';
 echo '</form>';
}

function inserer_default() {
 // if the submit button is clicked
 if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {
// sanitize form values
 $periodecite = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-period"] );
 $ville = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-ville"] );
 $Author = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-author"] );
 $Editor = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-editor"] );
 $Controbutor = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-contrub"] );
 $Abonne = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-abonne"] );

// Code de traitement du formulaire : insertion dans la BD
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("

UPDATE `wwpa_default` SET 
defPeriodecite ='".$periodecite."'
defVille ='".$ville."'
defUserAuthor ='".$Author."'
defUserEditor ='".$Editor."'
defUserControbutor ='".$Controbutor."'
defUserAbonne ='".$Abonne."'
WHERE 1

"));
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting?

Comment: no i dosn't turn any error, just don't change any thing

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this, check your update query

```
function test_defaultval() {
 echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '"
method="post">';
 echo '<p>';
 echo 'perdiodecite (requis) <br />';
 echo '<input type="text" name="cf-period" required pattern="[0-1]+"
size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';
 echo '<p>';
 echo 'ville (requis) <br />';
 echo '<input type="text" name="cf-ville" required size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';
 echo '<p>';
 echo 'author (requis) <br />';
 echo '<input type="text" name="cf-author" required pattern="[0-1]+"
size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';
 echo 'editor (requis) <br />';
 echo '<input type="text" name="cf-editor" required pattern="[0-1]+"
size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';
 echo 'contrubutor (requis) <br />';
 echo '<input type="text" name="cf-contrub" required pattern="[0-1]+"
size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';
 echo 'abonne (requis) <br />';
 echo '<input type="text" name="cf-abonne" required pattern="[0-1]+"
size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';

 echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted"
value="Enregistrer"/></p>';
 echo '</form>';
}


function inserer_default() {
 // if the submit button is clicked
 if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {
// sanitize form values
 $periodecite = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-period"] );
 $ville = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-ville"] );
 $Author = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-author"] );
 $Editor = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-editor"] );
 $Controbutor = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-contrub"] );
 $Abonne = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-abonne"] );



// Code de traitement du formulaire : insertion dans la BD
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( 
UPDATE `wwpa_default` SET 
defPeriodecite ='".$periodecite."',
defVille ='".$ville."',
defUserAuthor ='".$Author."',
defUserEditor ='".$Editor."',
defUserControbutor ='".$Controbutor."',
defUserAbonne ='".$Abonne."'
WHERE 1);
 }
}
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: thank you for you reply , but i tryied it's not working